# Internal Links in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of internal links I want to use for the first website I'm building.  It works great when I run it locally but none of the internal links work when on the actual site.  For example, here is one internal link I'm using.

```
<a href ="file:///C:/Users/17249/OneDrive/Dive%20Platform/National%20Popular%20Vote.html">Read More</a>
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but what link can I put there if one doesn't exist yet?  I guess how do I create sub pages for my website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use relative path, because there's no C: drive on server where you deploy

Comment: What do you mean by "... if one doesn't exist yet?" Do you mean the page that you refer to in the `href`?

Comment: You need to read a little bit more about URLs. Take a look at official documentation from W3C: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's simple example, You cannot use absolute path on server, but relative using `..` (back to parent directory) or `.` (current) to link to file that you need.

If you don't have a page yet, leave it `#`
like `<a href="#">Click here</a>`

[image]

Comment: so if I have a my index.html and then just a page named "test".  I would use "./test/index.html"

Comment: Depends on where you put these files. If index.html and test.html in the same folder level, just use "./test.html" in index.html

Comment: Thanks I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

You can put relative links in each page. Lets assume your site hierarchy is such:

```
index.html  

category-a.html  
category-a/page1.html  
category-a/page2.html

category-b.html  
category-b/page1.html
category-b/page2.html

The link from index.html to category-a.html would be: 
<a href="./category-a.html">category a</a>

The link from category-a.html to category-a/page1.html would be: 
<a href="./category-a/page1.html">page 1 of category a</a>

The link from category-a/page1.html to index.html would be:
<a href="../index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Where do I set the links though, so that it knows which link goes with which page?

Comment: In each file, according to it's relative place to the page you want to link to. Try